# Aligned load/store with NEON intrinsics in GCC

Tags: gcc, arm, simd, neon

How can you make GCC generate load/store instructions for aligned access?

If we have something like:

```
uint8_t* p;
uint8x8x4_t r = vld4_u8(p);
```

How can you make GCC genereate a load instruction that requires 32 bytes alignment?

Comment: It's `(*p)` you need to align, on the stack, heap, etc., before passing its address via a pointer.

Comment: With Microsoft Visual C++, there's a ``ex`` version of the intrinsic (``vld4_u8_ex``) to indicate an aligned load.

Comment: I checked the intrinsics macros, and found nothing with alignment specifiers. Maybe you can define some of your own with specifiers that meet your needs, or write the code in asm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use __builtin_assume_aligned(ptr, size);

e.g.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

void blend4(uint8_t *src, uint8_t *dst)
{
    uint8_t *aligned_src = __builtin_assume_aligned(src, 16);
    uint8_t *aligned_dst = __builtin_assume_aligned(dst, 16);
    uint8x8x4_t temp = vld4_u8(aligned_src);
    vst4_u8(aligned_dst, temp);
}
```

Generates:

```
vld4.8  {d16-d19}, [r0:128]
vst4.8  {d16-d19}, [r1:128]
```